# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' .I can't

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple question. `dizi` is an array of strings. I can't sort it numerically for int.

I want to sort as number array.

```
string[] dizi = new string[40];

for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    dizi[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
}

Array.Sort(dizi);
label2.Text = dizi[0];
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error in the title?

Comment: See [Writing The Perfect Question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Comment: no error.But Array is sort but string sort.

Comment: I want to int sort.
Example : dizi[]={"15","25","45,"100","120"};
Sort =>>>100,120,15,25,45

Comment: I want value to {15,25,45,100,120}

Comment: Parse your string values to integer, put them in your array and sort your array.

Comment: @FatihDemir just sort as an array of `int` first, then use `ToString()` when you need to display in the `Label` kindly take a look on my proposed answer. You may want to consider using `int.TryParse` to as a safe-guard error for wrong string format in the `listBox` items

Comment: @FatihDemir: If your values are supposed to be integers, store them as integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to sort the `listbox` items by putting them into an `Array`, but at the same time, you also have changed the `listbox` items into array of `string` and `string` cannot be sorted by descending/ascending as `int` does

In that case, you should rather get your `listbox` items as `Array` of `int` and then sort it as `int` before displaying it in your `Label` as `string`

```
int[] dizi = new int[listBox1.Items.Count]; //here is int array instead of string array, put generic size, just as many as the listBox1.Items.Count will do
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    dizi[i] = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i].ToString()); 
    //assuming all your listBox1.Items is in the right format, the above code shall work smoothly, 
    //but if not, use TryParse version below:
    //  int listBoxIntValue = 0;
    //  bool isInt = int.TryParse(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), out listBoxIntValue); //Try to parse the listBox1 item
    //  if(isInt) //if the parse is successful
    //      dizi[i] = listBoxIntValue; //take it as array of integer element, rather than string element. Best is to use List though
    //here, I put the safe-guard version by TryParse, just in case the listBox item is not necessarily valid number. 
    //But provided all your listBox item is in the right format, you could easily use Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i].ToString()) instead
}

Array.Sort(dizi); //sort array of integer
label2.Text = dizi[0].ToString(); //this should work
```

This way, `dizi` would be a sorted version of you `listbox1` items as `int`. Whenever you need this as `string` just use `ToString()` for the array element

Also, as a side note: consider of using `List` of `int` and `int.TryParse` to get the integer element value from the `listBox.Items` in case you are not sure if all the `listBox.Items` can be converted to `int` for one reason or another.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to ints as you remove from the list box

```
int[] dizi = new int[40];
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
     dizi[i] = Convert.toInt32(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
     }

Array.Sort(dizi);
label2.Text= Convert.toString(dizi[0]);
```

Comment: I didnt use toInt32(...)

Comment: I added it for you to solve your problem.